# NullPointerException at FragmentActivity.onStart()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

My MainActivity extends a `CustomFragmentActivity`, that extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`... At MainActivity, I override the onStart method and set an static boolean at the `CustomFragmentActivity`... then, I call `super.onStart`, so this boolean is used to know if I should or not send a hit to google analytics...

As I use Crashlytics on my app, I'm getting the following crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.maisapp/br.com.maisapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:368)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
   at br.com.app.CustomFragmentActivity.onStart(CustomFragmentActivity.java:77)
   at br.com.app.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:192)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1631)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

So far I didnt made it to reproduce this crash. Here is the onStart at MainActivity (line 192 is the super.onStart() call)

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    isMain=true;
    super.onStart();
    try{
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }catch (Exception e){
        LogUtil.log(TAG, "onStart: Não executou Session.getActiveSession().addCallback()...");
        LogUtil.log(TAG, e, true);
    }

}
```

at CustomFragmentActivity, the onStart is as below:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!isMain){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getGaTracker().send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
    }
}
```

I instantiate isMain as: `protected static boolean isMain = false;`

While debuggin I cound't generate any exception, no matter if onStart is called after onCreate (when app is open) or after onRestart (when MainActivity has been stopped).. Any ideas which direction should I take to figure this out?

Comment: check the isMain in the CustomFragmentActivity via debug (Watch) and see it's null

Comment: @A.S. is it even possible for isMain to be null at runtime, as I'm instantiating it statically? Also I can't assign null to isMain because boolean is a primitive datatype...

Comment: What is probably triggering this is you have a dialog open and the screen is rotated. It's happening to me as well but I'm not sure the solution. You may be able to set the DialogFragment to setRetainInstance(true) in the onCreate for the DialogFragment, but then the dialog does not stay visible across orientation change.